# How to change Wamp64's browsing language?

Tags: php, browser, wamp

I work on a project where I am crawling web pages using PHP and Wamp64.

When I am loading a page from an URL using PHP, I get the content of the page in french and I would like to get it in english.
The default browser of Wamp is chrome (the one that I am using) and wamp and chrome are set in english.
When I browse the URL myself the page is in english but when I load it using PHP and Wamp I still get the  content of the page in french.

This is the method I'm using to crawl a page :

```
$search = 'a movie title';  

$urlImdb = 'http://www.imdb.com';
$url = $urlImdb.'/search/title/?title='.urlencode(strtolower($search)).'&title_type=feature,tv_movie,tv_series,&view=advanced';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$main = $dom->getElementById('main');

// manipulating the dom to get the content I'm looking for
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What method are you using in PHP to download the web pages?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I edited my question, now you can see the method I'm using. Thanks.

Comment: IMDB geolocates the IP address for the request and applies a language based on that unless there's some reason to choose something else. I'd guess therefor that you're located in France.I thought that simply adding an `Accept-Language` header would change the language used by IMDB. This can't be done with `DOMDocument`, but you can do it with `cURL`, so scrape with that and use `DOMDocument` to parse the result. That didn't work either. Interestingly, I can't get IMDB to send anything other than English to me, even with French set as a browser language.

Comment: Apparently one can set the language if one opens an account, but I have no idea how you'd use that to scrape data. You could go for the API, but that incurs cost.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Yeah, I tried many differents way to define a language too, none of them are working. And i saw the API but indeed that includes cost... Anyway thanks for taking time to search for a solution, I'll try to find another way. Thanks :)